# SVN authentification failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, svn

After recovering a login and password, I want to connect to the SVN repository (http://source:8080/svn/.../test.xml )and to access, the goal is to use a XML file from there in my code.
How to proceed the configuration to connect to the svn repository after recovering login & pwd

Any help will be appreciate,
Thanks

**Answer :**

when I work with a local URL, it works good like this

```
public List<XElement> TableReqDAL(string fichier)
    {
      XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("D:\\..."+fichier+".xml");  (...)     
    }
```

but when I  put the SVN repository URL

```
 public List<XElement> TableReqDAL(string fichier)
    {
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("http://source:8080/svn/.../"+fichier+".xml");   
         (...)              
    }
```

it doesn't work, I understand that there is a configuration that I must do it to use the desired file from the svn repository but I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Your question's title suggests that authentication is failing, but you haven't said how you're trying to authenticate.

Comment: Sorry I've put the answer in my question

Answer (score 0):

[SubversionSharp](http://www.softec.lu/site/ClrProjects/SubversionSharp) is a good solution for your problem

Comment: are you using any API to connect to SVN ?

Comment: no, which API you think that I must use, and how to use it.. thanks in advance

Comment: Use the one I have mentioned in the answer svnsharp

Comment: I've add the API of SubversionSharp, how can I now connect to the svn repository and use my file ?